# Vlookup Count ifs

Tags: excel

I have a set data as follow :

Sheet 1 : 
Names at Colomn A (the names can be written more than once) ex : adam, adam, andi
Status at colomn B (the status can be written more than once) : ex good,Late,busy

What can heppens is That Adam might have status late, but on the other row adam might have status good.

Sheet 2 :
Names at colomn A
Status at colomn B (good) and colomn C (late)

So can someone please tell me, if I want to count how many times did adam did good and how many times did adam did late ?

I tried at sheet 2 under colomn B this formula

```
=COUNTIF('Sheet 1'!A:AZ,VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet 1'!C:AZ,2,0),'Sheet 1'!A:AZ,VLOOKUP(B1,'Sheet 1'!C:AZ,2,0))
```

but seems not working

Comment: Why don't you create a simple pivot table in sheet2 !

Comment: If you have Excel 2013 or later, use `COUNTIFS()` (with an 'S'). You don't need any VLookup here.

Comment: Honestly I'm doing it at google excel spreadsheet, I tried countifs but does not works.

Comment: Pivot table was the best easiest option! Thank You!